# Image Changing back in tableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift5

I am creating a tableView with a button(with an image A) inside the cell. On clicking the button , the button's image should change from A -> B and it is changing . But when I am scrolling down and coming back up the image of the clicked button changed back to A .How to solve this ?

Comment: I have one more question . Where should i define my button outlet and the button tapped action . In the UITableViewCell or the VC that is using that cell . When I am defining them  in cell this is happening -- I clicked the button  , image changed from A to B , but when I am scrolling down , the image is already change to B in some of the cells .But the issue of image changing back to A is not there for already tapped button When i am assigning the outlet and action in VC , while scrolling down the button image is A only but buttons that I clicked are not retaining its state (B)

Comment: outlet of button will be added in cell class and action can be added in both cell class and view class, changing of image on scrolling happens if you dont handle else case then in this case cell take default image.

Comment: hi yash. this is not a "we write code for you"-platform. show us what you tried so far. give us copyable runnable reproducable code, then we can help you. and please read and consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Table view reuse your cell when you scrolling. Try save the button status in a mode, and restore the status in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

Let me try this again. When you use UITableView, the cells will be reused. Thus, you will need a way to track each cell's "button" state. There are many ways to approach this but I can recommend using an array of "bool"s that track if a button was toggled or not. Then, create a check in the ViewController that is handling the cells to check the array of "bool"s to update a button if it was pressed. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, When you change from A->B, you should take image from Model class. On clicking the button, image should update on Model class, after that any time scrolling down tableview(cellForRowAt) it takes proper image (like B), because you set the button image from Model class in method of cellForRowAt.